# trigonometry and integral properties

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

So' I have a test next week and I need to answer some question as fast as I can (true or false question).

So I have the following question:

$$\int\limits_u^1 \frac{1}{1+x^{2}} = \int\limits_1^\frac{1}{u} \frac{1}{1+x^{2}}, \quad \forall u \in (0,1).$$

So I simplified the question as I know to

$\arctan 1 - \arctan u = \arctan \frac{1}{u} - \arctan1$

$2\arctan 1 = \arctan \frac{1}{u} + \arctan u$

$2\frac{\pi}{4} = \arctan \frac{1}{u} + \arctan u$

$\frac{\pi}{2} = \arctan \frac{1}{u} + \arctan u$

But I do know how to more than that.

Is there any tips you can give me how to solve those type of question (like identities or the $sin$ function is odd and so on in order to solve those questions).

And by the way, what is the answer for this question.

How do I continue from here (or maybe there need to be a falsifiability here).

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: You actually lack the question. What you show is an equality. I reckon the exercise is "Show/prove that ..."

Comment: Yes, I try to reach to a true or false statement which I already know

Answer (score 2):

Try to use the change of variable $u=\frac{1}{t}$. Or since you get the relation $\frac{\pi}{2} = \arctan(1/u)+\arctan u$ (which is true for $u\in (0,+\infty)$), you can study the function $u\mapsto \arctan(1/u)+\arctan u$ on $(0,+\infty)$ and calculate its derivative.

Comment: So This is a constant function when $x>0$

Comment: In fact, yes. You can also prove that this is a constant function on $(-\infty,0)$ but the constant is different.

Comment: You saying the constant is not $\frac{\pi}{2}$ ?

Comment: On $(-\infty,0)$ is a different constant but on $(0,+\infty)$, this is the right constant.